# Aligning icon class

Tags: css, glyphicons

As you can see by the image. The icon sits high. Any margin or padding I seem to try moves the text box down with it. With it positioned extra high, it also pushed the search text up. Any suggestions on how to fix?

I just want the search icon to be the same height and even with the search box and not mess with the label text.

[image]

```css
.icon-btn {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
}
.icon-magnifier-dark:before {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  content: "\e035";
  color: @color-light;

font-family: outlinedFont;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <label for="Search" style="">Search</label>

  <input type="text" name="Search" id="Search" size="10" style="" />
  <a class="icon-btn" href="#" style="">
    <i class="icon-magnifier-dark" style=""></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: try `vertical-align: bottom` on your search button

Comment: The align moves it down a pixel or 2, but that's about it.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle if possible?

Comment: I think some other css might be overriding or changing the aligning, so you should check your full css. I checked your JSFiddle which you provided in comment on one of the answer, I saw the aligning was OK in the Fiddle.

Comment: You are correct Rohit. I took the code to a blank page and your suggestion worked. Looks like bootstrap is overriding something. Thanx. Can't mark yours as the answer tho. If you want to post it to the answers, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some other `CSS` might be overriding or changing the aligning, so you should check your full CSS once. I checked your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnu286es/) which you provided in comment on one of the answer, I saw the aligning was OK in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

change `font-size`

```
font-family: outlinedFont;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Looks exactly the same except everything is moved down, label, input and icon.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hnu286es/ Don't know how to add the icon class on there, but the border should be equally spaced vertically with the search box.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's just best if I make it into a regular image. The smaller font doesn't look right either since it's too small. Aligns to the top, but not the middle or the same height as the input box.

Answer (score 0):

You made it so difficult. Please Check this code below...

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <label for="Search" style="">Search</label>

  <input type="text" name="Search" id="Search" size="10" style="" />
  <a class="icon-btn" href="#" style="">
    <i class="icon-magnifier-dark" style=""></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.icon-btn {
     display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.icon-magnifier-dark:before {
   content: "\e035";
   font-family: outlinedFont;
   font-style: normal;
}

input[type="text"]{
    width:150px;
    height:26px;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Check the demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktbgp7b7/)

Comment: That means that the input field would then be misaligned with all the others and I would have to put that on every field on the site for 1 button.